# Get values from SvelteKit's $app/stores outside of the lifecycle of a component

Tags: fetch, store, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

My Svelte components import readable stores like this:

```js
import { classes, locations, schedule } from 'stores.ts'
```

In stores.ts, I want to build the URL for fetch dynamically using page.host from $app/stores.

```js
// Note: this is not a Svelte component; it's stores.ts
import { readable } from 'svelte/store'
import { getStores } from '$app/stores'
const { page } = getStores()
let FQDN
page.subscribe(({ host }) => {
  FQDN = host
})

const getArray = async (url) => {
  const response: Response = await fetch(url)
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Bad response trying to retrieve from ${url}.`)
  return await response.json()
}

const getReadableStore = (url: string) => readable([], set => {
  getArray(`http://${FQDN}${url}`)
    .then(set)
    .catch(err => console.error('Failed API call:', err))
  return () => {}
})

export const classes = getReadableStore('/api/class/public.json')
export const locations = getReadableStore('/api/location/public.json')
export const schedule = getReadableStore('/api/schedule/public.json')
```

The sixth line throws this error...

> Error: Function called outside component initialization
> at get_current_component (/Users/nates/dev/shy-svelte/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:652:15)
> at Proxy.getContext (/Users/nates/dev/shy-svelte/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:685:12)
> at Module.getStores (/.svelte-kit/dev/runtime/app/stores.js:17:26)
> at eval (/src/stores.ts:6:38)
> at instantiateModule (/Users/nates/dev/shy-svelte/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e9a16784.js:68197:166)

Two questions...

1. What is the correct way to get page values from $app/stores outside of the context of a component? Is this possible? **Answer from below: No, this is not possible outside the context of a component.**
2. If I'm accessing a SvelteKit site, let's say `http://localhost:3000/something` or `https://example.com` and a Svelte component loads a readable store from stores.ts, is there a way in stores.ts to determine whether the original page request that loaded the component (which loaded from stores.ts) was **http** or **https**? **Answer from below: No, this is not possible in stores.ts - only from a component.**

**UPDATE:** Based on the feedback, I'm going to set a value in my .env called VITE_WEB_URL=http://localhost:3000 and change it for the production system. This cuts down on the number of lines of code and may be a better practice (comments welcome)...

```js
// revised stores.ts
import { readable } from 'svelte/store'

const { VITE_WEB_URL } = import.meta.env

const getArray = async (url) => {
  const response: Response = await fetch(url)
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Bad response trying to retrieve from ${url}.`)
  return await response.json()
}

const getReadableStore = (url: string) => readable([], set => {
  getArray(`${VITE_WEB_URL}${url}`)
    .then(set)
    .catch(err => console.error('Failed API call:', err))
  return () => {}
})

export const classes = getReadableStore('/api/class/public.json')
export const locations = getReadableStore('/api/location/public.json')
export const schedule = getReadableStore('/api/schedule/public.json')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Extract from https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-stores

> Because of that, the stores are not free-floating objects: they must be accessed during component initialisation, like anything else that would be accessed with getContext.

2. Therefore, since the readable store is bound to the context of a svelte component, I suggest you subscribe either way ($ or .subscribe) inside the component of the SvelteKit website and then send the protocol value (http or https) as parameter when it updates so that stores.ts stores it in a variable.

However, it looks like SvelteKit does not provide the protocol value, so parse the client side window.location.href in the page subscription and then send it.

Comment: Thanks - makes sense

Comment: `console.log("protocol: ", window.location.protocol);`  `Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined.`  Sigh.  I'm assuming Server Side Rendering...  Or am I the only person who develops in `http:` before going live with `https://` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Referencing a svelte store can be done everywhere.
   Using the $: shorthand syntax, however, only works within a component.
2. 

```js
$: BASE = `http://${$page.host}`
```

3. SvelteKit appears to delegate this to fetch indeed

Comment: Only works in .svelte files - not .ts.